# Let $y = a x^2 + bx + c$. Find the minimizing conic in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Polynomial regression problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 9\\
1 & 4 & 16
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
b\\
a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
5\\
7\\
10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We have
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 9\\
1 & 4 & 16
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad
x = [c,b,a]^T$$
We are going to find a parabola $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ that fits the four data points $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, $(3,7)$, and $(4,10)$ as closely as possible.

We have
$y = [6,5,7,10]^T$. The solution to this least-squares problem is given by
$$x^* = (A^T A)^{-1}A^T y$$
which gives the coefficients of the parabola that minimizes the sum of squared distances to the data points. We obtain
$$x^* =
\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
b\\
a
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
8.5\\
-3.6\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore, the minimizing parabola is given by
$$y = 1x^2 - 3.6x + 8.5$$

Could you check my calculation? Because I'm not sure...

Comment: Not what you want, but here are [two parabolas through the four points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udoYH.png).

Comment: Your calculations are correct.